# Plotly dash label dcc compoenent

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Is there an argument to label a dcc component in Plotly dash or do i have to insert an own html tag for that?
For example for this RadioItems selection between a log or a linear plot, is there the opportunity to name this component "choose between linear or log", so that it shows up when rendering the dash app?

```
html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='secondary_yaxis',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
        value =  "CO2",
        multi = True
    ),
```

Comment: There is no `label` property for Dropdown component, but you can set a `placeholder` with a default text that is shown when no option is selected. Otherwise you will have to use a specific html component.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give **dash-mantine-components** a try.

```py
import dash_mantine_components as dmc


dmc.MultiSelect(
    id="secondary_yaxis",
    label="Choose between linear or log",
    description="You can also provide a description here",
    data=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in ["CO2"]],
    value=["CO2"]
)
```

Output:
[image]
You can install it via: `pip install dash-mantine-components`

> PS: I'm the author of this library. I don't have very good documentation for now, but I'd be happy to help you while I create one.